# Virtualtype admin grid filter data collection in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, grid, filter

I created an admin grid using virtual type in di.xml like this:

```
<virtualType name="Namespace\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Test\Grid\Collection" type="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\SearchResult">
   <arguments>
      <argument name="mainTable" xsi:type="string">module_test</argument>
      <argument name="resourceModel" xsi:type="string">Namespace\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Test\Collection</argument>
   </arguments>
</virtualType>
```

i want to filter the data by the id that passed via an url like this:

```
http://localhost/admin/namespace_module/test/index/test_id/<id>/key/<form_key>
```

I want my grid to load only data that contain only test_id which sent via url

```
<column name="test_id">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="label" translate="true" xsi:type="string">test_id</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you have this in your ui component :

```
<item name="update_url" path="mui/index/render" xsi:type="url"/>
```

then add this code below above code:

```
<item name="filter_url_params" xsi:type="array"> 
     <item name="test_id" xsi:type="boolean">1</item>
 </item>
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using a virtual type, you need to create a class which extends `\Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\SearchResult` and has a `_beforeLoad` method where the `test_id` filter is applied.
Example:

```
use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\Db\FetchStrategyInterface as FetchStrategy;
use Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\EntityFactoryInterface as EntityFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface as EventManager;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface as Logger;

class Collection extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\SearchResult
{
    protected $request;

    public function __construct(
        EntityFactory $entityFactory,
        Logger $logger,
        FetchStrategy $fetchStrategy,
        EventManager $eventManager,
        $mainTable = 'module_test',
        $resourceModel = 'Namespace\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Test\Collection',
        RequestInterface $request
    ) {
        $this->request = $request;

        parent::__construct($entityFactory, $logger, $fetchStrategy, $eventManager, $mainTable, $resourceModel);
    }

    public function _beforeLoad()
    {
        // show only items with passed in parameter
        if ($testId = $this->request->getParam('test_id')) {
            $this->addFieldToFilter('test_id', $testId);
        }

        return parent::_beforeLoad();
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice answer. However I have to mention that dynamic variable from request doesn't work in dataprovider (tested in magento 2.3). I have to get value from request in controller and store into session. Example answer here https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/259044/dynamic-value-not-working-in-addfieldtofilter