# Dynamic value not working in addFieldToFilter

Tags: magento2, admin, grid, uicomponent

I have a data provider to filter data in admin grid magento2, so I do:

```
namespace vendor\module\Ui\Component\DataProvider\SearchResult;

class Items extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\SearchResult
 protected function _initSelect()
    {  
    //$name is a varible get data from Request URL like:
     $name = substring($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], 5, 6);
    // and ..
    $this->addFieldToFilter('name', $name); // not working
    // but with static $name like
    $this->addFieldToFilter('name', "john"); // working
}
```

Comment: did you try $name = "john". or print the variable $name.

Comment: yes,  $name = "john" is working but with dynamic value not working

Comment: then there is a problem with substring($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], 5, 6); check what output you are getting from substring($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], 5, 6);

Comment: using super global variables($_SERVER,$_GET,$_POST,$_REQUEST...etc) in magento not a recommended way.

Comment: with debugging, I have get the value $name="john", but not working, Its working with static variable. I think its other logic in magento2, Do you have a solution ? tks you!

Comment: same problem here

Answer (score 1):

I just fixed it by using mentioned below steps

1. Store param value in session in controller

   public function execute()
   {
   $this->_catalogSession->setTokenId($this->request->getParam('entity_id'));
   $this->_view->loadLayout();
   $this->_view->loadLayoutUpdates();
   $this->_view->getPage()->getConfig()->getTitle()->set(__('Redeem Token History'));
   $this->_view->renderLayout();
   }
2. Use session value in dataprovider

   $tokensCollection->addFieldToFilter('token_id', ['eq' => $this->_catalogSession->getTokenId()]);

Enjoy :)